# How to embed icon in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[image]

How can I design something similar to this, is that a unicode icon or imageview ?

Answer (score 1):

Differents options could be possible :

- With an **image** (png / gif or webp)

Good solution : but you maybe not able to make all that designs, especially if you have a lot of icons to designs

- With **unicode**

Easy solution : But becareful you not control what's appears. The displayed icon depend of your device / os / webbrowser

- With a special **font or an icon library** ex : https://fontawesome.com/

Could be a little bit heavy If you need only one icon, but nice solution to have some pertinent worked icons (easy and fast to use for a dev)